# SFML 2.1 sf::Text.setString() causes crash when selected font is loaded from memory

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

If i use 'loadFromFile()' on my font, it loads it correctly and the game runs.
However, if i use this example code here:

```
                sf::Font TempFont;
                //TempFont.loadFromMemory(&tempImageVec[0],lengthh);
                TempFont.loadFromFile("Arial.ttf");
                WorldPointer->loadedFonts.push_back(TempFont);
                //WorldPointer->loadedFonts[WorldPointer->loadedFonts.size()-1].loadFromMemory(&tempImageVec[0],lengthh);
                WorldPointer->loadedFontNames.push_back("Arial");
```

It works completely, the font can be drawn to the game, however if i do this:

```
            std::streampos lengthh;
            std::ifstream file2("Arial.ttf", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
            if(file2){
                file2.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
                lengthh = file2.tellg();
                file2.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
                vector<char> tempImageVec(lengthh);
                file2.read(&tempImageVec[0],lengthh);
                sf::Font TempFont;
                TempFont.loadFromMemory(&tempImageVec[0],lengthh);
                WorldPointer->loadedFonts.push_back(TempFont);
                WorldPointer->loadedFontNames.push_back("Arial");
            }
```

(Note that this code works exactly the same as .loadFromFile(), however it does it manually, it loads the Arial.ttf file into the games memory, then it loads the font from the memory, this exact method works for other classes in SFML (Like textures))

When using the second code, the game compiles, however, when trying to use .setString("Any text here"); the game crashes, using the exact same sprite codes.

Both of these codes should react the same, but the second one (Which is the one i want to use) screws the game up.

I'm using SFML 2.1 with codeblocks

Heres the debug stuff:

```
#0 0048DD0C tt_cmap4_char_map_binary () (??:??)
#1 004938E6 tt_cmap4_char_index () (??:??)
#2 0043C1A1 FT_Load_Char () (??:??)
#3 004128C2 sf::Font::loadGlyph(this=0x7069208, codePoint=32, characterSize=25, bold=false) (D:\developpement\sfml\sfml\src\SFML\Graphics\Font.cpp:388)
#4 0041233E sf::Font::getGlyph(this=0x7069208, codePoint=32, characterSize=25, bold=false) (D:\developpement\sfml\sfml\src\SFML\Graphics\Font.cpp:259)
#5 004146CC sf::Text::updateGeometry(this=0x28fdc4) (D:\developpement\sfml\sfml\src\SFML\Graphics\Text.cpp:248)
#6 00413F50 sf::Text::setString(this=0x28fdc4, string=...) (D:\developpement\sfml\sfml\src\SFML\Graphics\Text.cpp:68)
#7 00405656 world::world(this=0x28f2e8, MRP=0x28f100) (C:\Users\Heath\Desktop\Game Programming\Current Projects\Left4Zombie C++\world.cpp:11)
#8 004038A3 main() (C:\Users\Heath\Desktop\Game Programming\Current Projects\Left4Zombie C++\main.cpp:12)
(LoadGlyph is highlighted red)
```

Comment: Could it be that the `sf::Font` ` object only stores the *pointer* to the data, and doesn't do a deep copy?

Comment: I think i just read that the stream needs to stay active, which sort of sucks, i will try to make the stream stay active and ill get back to you haha :P
@JoachimPileborg I think this is what you said yes?

Comment: Not the stream, but the pointer you get from `tempImageVec` needs to be valid during the lifetime of the font object. As it is now, when you leave the `if` body then the `tempImageVec` object is destructed and the pointer in the font object will no longer be valid.

Comment: Yeah, i kept the vector that holds all the memory alive, and it seems to be working now!
I never thought this would be the case though, as sf::Texture doesn't need the memory to work after it's loaded it..
Thanks for the quick help guys.